# Blend's Assets list is empty

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend, blend

Blend to Visual Studio 2012 have an empty assets list. Instead of items it shows a sendwatch coursor.

I don't found any way to fix or restore it.

I have tried to google but no result.

UP: It seems to be project related because all working correct while another project are editing.

Comment: I have this problem, I have a windows store app and windows phone app...tried removing the windows store but its the same problem...

Comment: Try to use this tool to check that you have any assets installed for your Blend: [Blend Assets Manager](http://blasm.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @AlekseyLarchenko, it works when i create new blank projects, but for some reason, if I have both a windows store and windows phone project in the same solution, it doesn't load any asset at all.

Comment: @Viacheslav, Did you find a way to make it work?

Comment: No, I don't found a solution to fix it.

Comment: I tried to google, too, and this page is the top result. :-/

Comment: Unfortunately I have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score -1):

Try to separate Windows Store and Windows Phone project in a different solution. Have you tried this? I have tried this and it works well on my machine.

The sad fact is, can be that Expression Blend 5 for Visual Studio was having trouble of separating assets for Windows Store and Windows Phone application within the same solution.